# What difference does it make changing the order of arguments to 'append'

Tags: list

I want to understand the implications of `append`'s property that "All arguments except the last one are copied, so none of the arguments is altered." (from the [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html))

Say I have a list `mylist` (the order of its elements is irrelevant),

```lisp
(setq mylist '(a b))
```

First, I want to add a couple of elements to it. Using `append` I can do

```lisp
(setq mylist
      (append mylist '(c d)))
```

or

```lisp
(setq mylist
      (append '(c d) mylist))
```

If I understand right, the resulting list is

```
mylist
|
|     --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |
        --> a        --> b        --> c        --> d
```

in the first case and

```
mylist
|
|     --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |
        --> c        --> d        --> a        --> b
```

in the second case. *Both settings leave nothing else in memory*, right?

Second, I want to concatenate `mylist` and `another-list` (again invariant wrt to the order of its elements),

```lisp
(setq another-list '(0 1))
```

(I'll use the first value of `mylist`). I can do

```lisp
(setq another-list
      (append mylist another-list))
```

or

```lisp
(setq another-list
      (append another-list mylist))
```

In my reasoning the first setting yields

```
another-list
|
|     --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |            |            |
        --> a        --> b        --> c        --> d        --> 0        --> 1
```

while `mylist` still resides unaltered somewhere in memory. The second setting yields

```
another-list              mylist
|                           |
|     --- ---      --- ---   -> --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |            |            |
        --> 0        --> 1        --> a        --> b        --> c        --> d
```

which is all the code I've used has put in memory, which is to say that compared with the first setting of `another-list` I've spared one copy of `mylist`. Is this right?

Last thing, when Emacs evaluates `(append mylist '(c d))` and `(append '(c d) mylist)`, what do they look like in memory? Can you show it with a cons cells diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty much it, but keep in mind that there is always more going on. For example, the source code that you type in is also read into a bunch of cons cells. This is true whether you're typing at the repl, or be reading from a source file. (Reading byte-compiled code will have a somewhat different result, but with identical semantics.)

Thus, after the very first `(setq mylist '(a b))`, you'll have this in memory:

```
┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐    ┌─┬─┐
│╷│╶┼─→│╷│╶┼───→│╷│/│
└┼┴─┘  └┼┴─┘    └┼┴─┘
 └→setq └→mylist │ ┌─┬─┐   ┌─┬─┐
                 └→│╷│╶┼──→│╷│/│
                   └┼┴─┘   └┼┴─┘
                    └→quote │ ┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐
                            └→│╷│╶┼─→│╷│/│
mylist───────────────────────→└┼┴─┘  └┼┴─┘
                               └→a    └→b
```

`mylist` is pointing to part of the source code, rather than to a new list.

Then, after running `(setq mylist (append mylist '(c d)))` you'll have the above plus this:

```
┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐    ┌─┬─┐
│╷│╶┼─→│╷│╶┼───→│╷│/│
└┼┴─┘  └┼┴─┘    └┼┴─┘
 └→setq └→mylist │ ┌─┬─┐     ┌─┬─┐    ┌─┬─┐
                 └→│╷│╶┼────→│ │╶┼───→│╷│/│
                   └┼┴─┘     └┼┴─┘    └┼┴─┘
                    └→append  └→mylist │
                                       │ ┌─┬─┐   ┌─┬─┐
                                       └→│╷│╶┼──→│╷│/│
                                         └┼┴─┘   └┼┴─┘
                                          └→quote │ ┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐
        ┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐                              └→│╷│╶┼─→│╷│/│
mylist─→│╷│╶┼─→│╷│╶┼───────────────────────────────→└┼┴─┘  └┼┴─┘
        └┼┴─┘  └┼┴─┘                                 └→c    └→d
         └→a    └→b
```

That is, `mylist` is now pointing to a list whose first two conses are new, but whose other conses are not.

This is why you never want to call `setcar`, `setcdr`, `nconc`, or any other function that modifies a value in place on any value that came directly from the reader; they will happily modify source code that you will want to run again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please make an example of something that doesn't come directly from the reader? (What is the reader?) Then, just for being sure, in the second row of the second code block I would have said that the cdr of "append" pointed to "mylist", not to "quote". Are you sure about that? What does the expansion of `(setq mylist (append '(c d) mylist))` look like?

Comment: Oh, I did get that backwards somehow. Let me edit it…

Comment: Excuse me for all the questions, you're really helping me understand.

Comment: Note also that in the second diagram, one `mylist` is a symbol, while the other is a pointer to the value within the previous expression. I guess I ought to draw that arrow in correctly as well.

Comment: @ArchStanton The reader is practically the Lisp interpreter; see [`(elisp) Streams Intro`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Streams-Intro.html).

Comment: Yes, specifically it's that part of the lisp interpreter which converts text into cons cells. You can invoke directly it by calling the `read` function, or indirectly by calling `load` or `require`, typing at a repl, `M-:`, etc, etc.

Comment: cc:@Basil So an example of something that comes directly from the reader is a constant list, and the problem with it is what's described at the end of [(elisp)Rearrangement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html), namely the "constant list as a non-last argument to nconc" pitfall, right?

Comment: @ArchStanton Everything comes from the reader, including `(list 1 2)`.  The difference is that each time `(list 1 2)` is evaluated, a fresh list object is created, whereas each time the constant `'(1 2)` is evaluated, the same list object might be returned.  Passing the latter as a non-last argument to `nconc` would modify the same list object globally, which means your program would exhibit different (undefined) behaviour each time it is run.  Constant literals are effectively part of the program source itself, and thus should be copied before being modified destructively.

Comment: The lisp reader takes *text* (the lisp code that you see in your text editor) and turns it all into lisp *objects* (which is what actually gets evaluated).  Typically the textual code is `read` once and the resulting objects may be `eval`'d repeatedly.  When something is `quote`d -- e.g. `'(1 2)` -- evaluating that form returns the object that the *reader* established (in this case a list which had the value `(1 2)` at the time it was read but, like any other list, is subject to manipulation, and so may not longer have that same value at a later evaluation.

Comment: > Note also that in the second diagram, one mylist is a symbol, while the other is a pointer to the value within the previous expression.
You mean that the second car in the second row in the second block actually points to the first car of the last row in the first block? Also, I can’t wrap my mind around what `(append '(c d) mylist)` would look like once read in. Can you please make a box diagram of its expansion?

Comment: No, I made a mistake and conflated evaluation with reading. The reader does not resolve variable names, so it produces a structure with just the symbol `mylist` in it. The evaluator sees the symbol and looks up the value for that symbol in the environment. The evaluator doesn't change the structure produced by the reader though, so there's never a link between them.

Comment: Also, `(append '(c d) mylist)` looks exactly like `(append mylist '(a b))` which I already showed, but obviously the arguments are in the opposite order.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's useful to contrast how `append` and `nconc` behave in this regard.

The way `nconc` concatenates its arguments is by modifying the end of each argument to point to the next argument.  It does so "destructively", meaning it modifies its arguments in-place, without first making a copy.

Here's an example.  **N.B.:** instead of using quoted constant lists like `'(1 2)` I am using `list` to allocate fresh list objects that are safe to modify; see [`(info "(elisp) Mutability")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mutability.html).

```el
(setq a (list 1 2))
(setq b (list 3 4))
(setq c (nconc a b))
```

Here's the resulting box diagram:

```
a, c                        b
|                           |
|     --- ---      --- ---   -> --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |
        --> 1        --> 2        --> 3        --> 4
```

What happened is `a` was traversed until its final cdr, which was modified in place to point to `b`.  As a result, `a` and `c` are both `equal` and `eq` now, but the new `a` is no longer `equal` to the old `a`.

By contrast, `b` was the last argument to `nconc` and thus the final tail of the concatenated list, so it wasn't even traversed, let alone modified.  In fact, the final tail doesn't even have to be a list; whatever it is is just slapped onto the end of the result as the final cdr:

```el
(nconc (list 1 2) 3) ;; => (1 2 . 3)
```

---

The way `append` concatenates its arguments is practically the same, except it makes a copy before modifying any argument (it also accepts sequences that aren't lists, but that's irrelevant here).  Using the same example as before, here's the resulting box diagram:

```
a
|
|     --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |
       |            |
        --> 1        --> 2

c                           b
|                           |
|     --- ---      --- ---   -> --- ---      --- ---
 --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
       |            |            |            |
       |            |            |            |
        --> 1        --> 2        --> 3        --> 4
```

What happened is `a` was copied, the copy's final cdr was modified in place to point to `b`, and the result was assigned to `c`.  As a result, `a` and `b` are still `equal` and `eq` to their previous selves, and `a` is neither `equal` nor `eq` to `c`.

Again, the final tail need not be a list, because it won't be traversed or copied:

```el
(append (list 1 2) 3) ;; => (1 2 . 3)
```

---

Back to your question:

> *Both settings leave nothing else in memory*, right?

Apart from objects that are no longer referred to and might eventually be garbage-collected, such as the original value of `mylist` of `'(a b)`.  See also [db48x's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62899/15748).

> which is to say that compared with the first setting of `another-list` I've spared one copy of `mylist`. Is this right?

Yes, as was the case with `b` in my example above.

> Last thing, when Emacs evaluates `(append mylist '(c d))` and `(append '(c d) mylist)`, what do they look like in memory? Can you show it with a cons cells diagram?

I think [db48x's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62899/15748) has already covered that.

HTH.