# nconc does not seem to update first parameter when its value is nil

Tags: list

I’m trying to add several values at once to a given list, which may be nil or already contain some other values.

After some research, I found the two following versions are working well:

```lisp
(let ((x '(a)))
 (setq x (append x '(b c)))
 x)
⇒ (a b c)

(let ((x '(a)))
 (nconc x '(b c)) 
 x)
⇒ (a b c)
```

However, if the "main" list is nil at the beginning, `nconc` does not seem to work as expected:

```lisp
(let (x)
 (setq x (append x '(b c)))
 x)
⇒ (b c)

(let (x) 
 (nconc x '(b c))
 x)
⇒ nil
```

Is someone able to explain the last exemple? I would have expected it to return `(b c)`. Did I miss something?

Just in case, I also tested with an empty list, same result:

```lisp
(let ((x '()))
 (nconc x '(b c))
 x)
⇒ nil
```

However, the following is working, but in that case I don’t see added value compared to `append`:

```lisp
(let (x) ;; work with an empty list too
 (setq x (nconc x '(b c)))
 x)
⇒ (b c)
```

Thank you very much to any explanation on this.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question. See the doc (Elisp manual) for `nconc` and other "destructive" functions that can modify list structure. In general, they do not modify structure if they don't need to. And more importantly here: they don't know about or care about variables that might point to parts of the structure. It's up to you to set a variable you care about to a possibly new value. So what you did using `setq` is necessary. See the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some existing explanations on this, see:

- the Elisp manual entry for `append` under [`(info "(elisp) Building Lists")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html), including the footnote;
- the Elisp manual entry for `nconc` under [`(info "(elisp) Rearrangement")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html);
- and a previous answer of mine on `append` and `nconc` [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62900/15748).

> ```el
> (let ((x '(a)))
>   (nconc x '(b c)) 
>   x)
> ```

**Don't do this.** `nconc` works by destructively modifying all but its last argument, but `x` in this case is a quoted list literal, which is not safe to modify; see [`(info "(elisp) Mutability")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mutability.html).

It is okay to use `nconc` if you know for sure that `x` is safe to modify, as in the following example:

```el
(let ((x (list 'a)))
  (nconc x '(b c))
  x)
```

If you are not sure whether `x` is safe to modify, use `append` instead, or make a copy of `x` first, e.g. using `copy-sequence`.

> Is someone able to explain the last exemple? I would have expect it to return `(b c)`. Did I miss something?

Yes.  What `nconc` does is link all of its arguments together, by modifying each argument (except the last) in-place to point to the next argument.

How would this work for a `nil` argument? The answer is it doesn't: appending an empty list to any other list is the same as not appending the empty list at all!

For example, `(nconc (list 1) () (list 2))` is equivalent to `(nconc (list 1) (list 2))`, which is `(1 2)` - the empty list is skipped.

Besides, even if it did make sense to link `nil` like any other list, then Emacs would complain, because `nil` is a protected constant that can't be modified.

> However, the following is working

Yes, that is the correct way to use `nconc` if you don't know ahead of time whether `x` will be empty.  If `x` is guaranteed to be non-`nil`, then using `nconc` without assigning the result back to same variable is fine.  If, OTOH, `x` might be `nil`, then you must assign the result back to some variable, otherwise the result will be lost.

> but in that case I don’t see added value compared to `append`

`append` makes a copy of all but its last argument.  It can also concatenate sequences of other types, like strings and vectors, in addition to lists.

By contrast, `nconc` is intended for a very specific purpose: linking mutable lists in-place and fast, without any extra memory allocations due to copying.  It is effectively a generalisation of `setcdr` that operates on the last link of any number of cons cells.

If you're not sure which of the two to use, it's safer to go with `append`.

Comment: Please consider adding a link to the Elisp manual, which covers this well. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Done, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very complete answer! I realize I still not understand some core concept of lisp :/ I read the documentation of both `nconc` and `append` before asking but did not find it very explicit. I think I now understand how `append` and `nconc` work but it still a bit blurry. I’ll need to test to understand.

However, if you don’t mind, could you elaborate a bit about mutable variable? I’m not sure to understand why `(list 'a)` is safer than `'(a)`. The mutability info node does not explain that :(

Thanks again

Comment: In your sample code, the `'(a)` is part of the source code you were running. Modifying it destructively thus also modifies the source code; if you were to run the same source code again then you would get different results.

Comment: @ÉtienneDeparis Each time you evaluate `(list 'a)` or `(string ?a)`, a new list/string is created, that is guaranteed to be unique from any other list/string with the same contents, i.e. `(eq (list 'a) (list 'a))` is always `nil`. By contrast, `'(a)` and `"a"` are treated as self-evaluating constants - it is possible, but not guaranteed, that `(eq '(a) '(a))` will be non-`nil`.  In particular, the byte-compiler will often share (aka "fold") the same literal whenever it reappears in a program, so modifying one of its appearances actually modifies all of its appearances.

Comment: @ÉtienneDeparis IOW, literals are treated as read-only data in a program, similar to literal strings in C - modifying them can result in unexpected/undefined behaviour, especially when the program is byte-compiled, and should thus be avoided.

Comment: Wow, ok I never realize that before. Thank you very much for your clear explanations!